# How can i Calculate a Queue length

Tags: python, simulation

`python` I am making a bank simulation table and I want to calculate the queue length how can I call the previous row arrival time or start time or any input(I want the queue length to calculate the current row and then go to previous row and do the same calculations) so the queue length can add up, I know how to calculate it but I hope someone tell me how to call the previous row.

```
import random 
from dataclasses import dataclass
IAT_list=[]
ST_list=[]
qcount=0
pointer=0
size=int(input('enter the number of customers :'))

for k in range(1,size+1):
    print("Enter the arrival time number for your {} customer:".format(k))
    placeholder=int(input())
    IAT_list.append(placeholder)
print("===================================================")    
for k in range(1,size+1):
    print("Enter the service time number for your {} customer:".format(k))
    placeholdertwo=int(input())
    ST_list.append(placeholdertwo)
print("===================================================")    
print("your IAT LIST IS :",IAT_list)
print("===================================================")    
print("your ST LIST IS :",ST_list)
print("===================================================")    

@ dataclass
class Row:
    IAT:int=0
    St:int=0
    Arrival:int=0
    Service_start:int=0
    Send:int=0
    waiting:int=0
    Qlen:int=0
    spend_time=0


    
simtable=[]
#first customer    
c1=Row()
Iat=(IAT_list[pointer])#Iat=random.choice(IAT_list)
St=(ST_list[pointer])#St=random.choice(ST_list)
c1.IAT=Iat
c1.ST=St
c1.Arrival=Iat
c1.Service_start=Iat
c1.Send=c1.Service_start+St
c1.waiting=0
c1.Qlen=0
c1.spend_time= c1.Send - c1.Arrival
simtable.append(c1)


#all customers    
for i in range(1,size):
    c=Row()
    pointer=pointer+1
    Iat=(IAT_list[pointer]) #IAT=random.choice(IAT_list)
    St=(ST_list[pointer])#ST=random.choice(ST_list)
    c.IAT=Iat
    c.ST=St
    c.Arrival=simtable[i-1].Arrival+Iat
    if c.Arrival>simtable[i-1].Send:
        c.Service_start=c.Arrival
        c.Send=c.Service_start+St
        c.waiting=0
    else:
        c.Service_start=simtable[i-1].Send
        c.waiting=simtable[i-1].Send-c.Arrival
        c.Send=c.Service_start+St
    c.spend_time= c.Send - c.Arrival 
    
    if simtable[i-1].Service_start > simtable[i-1].Arrival:
        qcount=qcount+1
    else:
        qcount=0   
    c.Qlen=qcount
      
      
      
        
    simtable.append(c)
print('Cust \t IAT \t ST \t arrival \t start \t end \t\t waiting \t Spend-Time \t Qlen')
i=0
for x in simtable:
   
    print(i+1,"\t",x.IAT,"\t",x.ST,"\t",x.Arrival,"\t\t",x.Service_start,"\t\t",x.Send,"\t\t",x.waiting,"\t\t",x.spend_time,"\t\t",x.Qlen)
    i+=1
```

Comment: This code is not runnable as is. It would be helpful to have a minimal working example here. Otherwise it's impossible to tell what libraries are being used, what the variables are, what is relevant to the question itself etc.

Comment: Also, please clarify the inputs, expected outputs, and the _specific_ problem you have getting the expected output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.